# This query ran against the "innovate-db" database, unless qualified by the query

Tags: amazon-web-services

im receiving this two errors: please help me .

1. Your query has the following error(s):

Output bucket doesn't exist: s3://aws-athena-query-results-041497399321-ap-southeast-1/Unsaved/2019/02/11/09e29893-68f8-42fd-ae1e-4af88b90d82e.csv

This query ran against the "innovate-db" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 09e29893-68f8-42fd-ae1e-4af88b90d82e.

2. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:12: Column 'created_at' cannot be resolved

This query ran against the "innovate-db" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: b2a0b094-1f4a-4485-bd6c-5d944802eb44.

how may i fix this errors.

Comment: The second error is saying that it doesn't know the `created_at` column. Take a look at your `CREATE TABLE` command to see whether it was defined. If you are still confused, please Edit your question and include the relevant parts from both the `CREATE TABLE` command and the command that generated the second error.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is saying that the chosen output bucket does not exist.

Click the **Settings** option in the Amazon Athena console and enter the name of a bucket that *does* exist.

The second error is saying that there is no column defined as `created_at`.